# How to detect cell selection in UITableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

How can I implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or something similar in my Swift app?

I have a populated Table View with several dynamic cells and I want to change views once a certain cell is selected.

I am able to get my head around it in Objective-C, but there is nothing on google to help me with Swift!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in Swift:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Just make sure you implement the `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Google didn't at all, I spent ages looking and just as long trying for myself... This presents me with another issue though. How do I make sure each individual cell performs a different segue?

Comment: Check the indexPath.row. It gives you the number of the row. Then you can use an if-else.

Comment: Awesome! Thankyou for the help, I'm finally starting to understand Swift a little better now :)

Comment: I would recommend you to read some tableview-tutorials from raywenderlich.com

Comment: Ill give that a look now!

Comment: Would this be the correct code to use? 

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveToSignIn", sender: self)
    }`

Comment: I want to make row 1 perform a different segue, but when i change the code to `indexPath.row == 1` it still performs the first segue?

Comment: Check if you've changed the segueIdentifier.

Comment: I have changed it, but using two if statements... is that correct?
`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveToSignIn", sender: self)
        }
        if indexPath.row == 1
        {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MoveTo2", sender: self)
        }`

Comment: You should ask another question. That way it will be seen by more Users.

Comment: Wow, indexPath.row was exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for UITableViewController. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I managed to segue from UITableView cells to other view controllers after implementing cellForRow, numberOfRowsInSection & numberOfSectionsInTable.

```
//to grab a row, update your did select row at index path method to:

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!");

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        //THE SEGUE 
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMainUI", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Will output: `You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!`

Remember to match the identifier of your segue in story board to the identifier in the function, e.g `goToMainUI`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to select cell at '0' index programmatically for collectionView.

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
}
```